# How can i run a loop on the first data frame and inner loop on second data frame to calculate the difference of their subject score student wise?

Tags: python, dask

Here is my first AND second data set.

[image: First Data set]

[image: Here is my second data set]

My target is to find the differences between first data set students with second datasets for their subject marks. I am doing it on python dask. And stuck on this phase. Anyone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Iterate the DFs:

```
import pandas as pd

data_A = {"student": ["st01", "st02"], "Math": [100, 75], "English": [100, 60]}
data_B = {"student": ["st01", "st02", "st03"], "Math": [100, 85, 90], "English": [100, 60, 70]}
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data=data_A, columns=['student', 'Math', 'English'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data=data_B, columns=['student', 'Math', 'English'])

for column in df_A.columns[1:]:
    print(f'Difference between group A and group B for subject {column}:'
          f' {abs(df_A[column].sum() - df_B[column].sum())}')
```